# Synonym proposal [meson] -> [meson-build]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

The tag descriptions are essentially the same and so the tagged questions are about the same thing. [meson-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meson-build) tag is better described and used in significantly bigger number of questions (partly because of my re-tagging work). But new users (not familiar with [meson-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meson-build)) continue using [meson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meson) simply because it comes first in search list, I guess, and because the tool that is invoked during build process is called **meson**.

Comment: I have already created synonym which is waiting for approval https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested